# Web-scraping on intranet

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, intranet

I wrote a VBA code to scrape data from my company's **intranet**.

**Issues:**

The below error occurs:

> Run-time error '91':
>   object variable or with block variable not set

It happens on:

```
myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("price")(0).getAttribute("value"))
```

When I debug it and run line by line, it can retrieve all the values.

**Input and Output:**

I input multiple product ID on column B and retrieve data on column C:
Column B = product ID
Column C = price

**HTML:**

```
<td id="myPower_val_9" style="visibility: visible;">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="300" name="price"></input>
</td>
```

**VBA:**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ie As Object
Dim r As Integer
Dim myPoints As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

For r = 2 To Range("B65535").End(xlUp).Row

    With ie
        .Visible = 0

        .navigate "www.example.com/product/" & Cells(r, "B").Value

        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

    Set Doc = ie.document

    myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("price")(0).getAttribute("value"))
    Cells(r, "C").Value = myPoints

Next r

End Sub
```

Have I missed an error handler?

Comment: did you debug the entire loop or just a single iteration? It may be that for a single iteration the webpage does not contain the required element. Try setting ie.visible=true and analyze the webpage when the error occurs.

Comment: @silentsurfer I looped the whole code, it only happen on that line. I try the similar code on us yahoo finance (internet) in my home and it works fine. Is there any error handler i could add to fix the code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the document to be fully rendered and the DOM available before accessing any elements. `ie.ReadyState` changes to `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` once the page connects and starts loading. The reason that your code works when debugging is that in the couple of seconds it takes for you to start working with the debugger, the page finishes loading.

```
With ie
   .Visible = True
   .Navigate "www.example.com/product/" & Cells(r, "B").Value

   Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       DoEvents
   Loop
   Do Until .Document.ReadyState = "complete"
       DoEvents
   Loop
End With
```

I would also recommend that you make the ie Window visible, at least while you're developing. Once you've got your functionality complete and debugging, you can make the window invisible. Keep in mind if you forget to close your invisible IE windows when your code finishes, your users will end up with runaway iexplore.exe processes.

Comment: I don't believe this is the answer. The asker's code already contains a loop waiting for ie.readyState to become equal to 4. (READYSTATE_COMPLETE equals 4 in the Internet Controls library)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer? Maybe I didn't word it carefully enough, but you need to check ie.ReadyState and ie.Document.ReadyState. ie.ReadyState becomes READYSTATE_COMPLETE before the document is fully loaded. Only when ie.Document.ReadyState == "complete" is the DOM completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to ignore the error and continue with the next iteration, use this modified code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ie As Object
Dim r As Integer
Dim myPoints As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument


Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium


For r = 2 To Range("B65535").End(xlUp).Row

With ie
  .Visible = 0

  .navigate "www.example.com/product/" & Cells(r, "B").Value

   Do Until .readyState = 4
   DoEvents
   Loop

End With


 Set Doc = ie.document


 'Edit:
 myPoints = ""

 On Error Resume Next
 myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("price")(0).getAttribute("value"))
 On Error Goto 0

 Cells(r, "C").Value = myPoints

Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also loop until element is set (add a timeout clause as well)

```
Dim a As Object
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set a = Doc.getElementsByName("price")
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop While a Is Nothing
```